# Error while debugging C++ in VS code using C++(windows)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

Anyone who is using VS code for debugging C++ by using GCC compiler in Windows 10 platform? I'm getting errors like some PDB files are missing or can't be opened from System32 directory. When i'm starting the debugging the program is getting executed without hitting the breakpoints. So what should i do about these PDB errors as i'm not able to use debugging functionality with these errors.

Comment: what's happened？

Comment: I'm unable to start debugging. Can you tell me the modifications to be done in tasks.json and launch.json files?

Answer (score 1):

my launch.json and task.json below.
make sure in your project folder there have a **build** folder 
launch.json

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",                
           "type": "cppdbg",                         
           "request": "launch",                        
           "targetArchitecture": "x86",                
           "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\build\\${fileBasename}.exe",                 
           "miDebuggerPath":"C:\\mingw-w64\\bin\\gdb.exe", 
           "args": [],     
           "stopAtEntry": false,                  
           "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",                  
           "externalConsole": true,                  
           "preLaunchTask": "g++"　　                  
           }
   ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "command": "g++",
   "args": ["-g","-std=c++11","${file}","-o","${workspaceRoot}\\build\\${fileBasename}.exe"],
   "problemMatcher": {
       "owner": "cpp",
       "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
       "pattern": {
           "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
           "file": 1,
           "line": 2,
           "column": 3,
           "severity": 4,
           "message": 5
       }
   }
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ]
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ]
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/include"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": "",
                "path": [
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ]
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 2
}
```

**folders**

[image]

Comment: Should i create a new folder named build and then  place the launch.json inside it?

Comment: you can create a new folder named build,but don't place the launch.json inside it.the launch.json and task.json you must place in the folder named .vscode,i have upload a image!

Comment: Got the debugging process started, but getting this error.

Comment: Unable to open 'istream.tcc': File not found (\home\gfortran\gcc-home\workshop\gcc\objdir\x86_64-w64-mingw32\libstdc++-v3\include\bits\i

Comment: make sure the "miDebuggerPath" correct.and then add a c_cpp_properties.json file.edit the "includePath"

Comment: In case of me here is the path    "miDebuggerPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gcc\\bin\\gdb.exe"